# Proper methods for cleaning window sill

Tags: windows, cleaning

See photo.  I'm not even sure I'm using the right terminology, because I don't know the name of this type of window.

It's very hard to get these areas clean from the inside. Is it truly necessary to remove the screen, open the window, wet, and spray out this funk?

The ridges that make the seal just seem to fight against anything being removed from the area.

If you know the type of window and a better way to ask this question, I welcome new title/clarity suggestions!

[image]

Comment: Removing window screens is pretty easy. Once you figure out how the latches work it should only take a few seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Cleaning them:

1. If I have good access from outside I push up screen (or remove), close window and hit it with a hose or power washer - from a decent distance.
2. Open window and get everything wet.  Soap and hot water.  With one paper towel you can take away 90% of the dirt on one window.
3. Use old toothbrush, old butter knife, and a washcloth on the rest.
4. Dry them with a clean rag.
5. Apply a marine wax ([here](http://www.meguiarsdirect.com/product/clear-plastic-and-vinyl-window-wax) is a brand I have used with good results).  By waxing it you are not ridding yourself of window cleaning.  However I have found that a lot less stuff will stick to your window sill/track in the short term (6 months).

Aside from shuttering up your windows, you will always get dirt in thise area.